# Get value from nested tuple

Tags: erlang, tuples, elixir

Here's a nested tuple from some Erlang library:

```
tuple = {:Certificate,
          {:TBSCertificate,
           :v3,
           3464270192823392628,
           {:AlgorithmIdentifier, {1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 1, 11}, <<5, 0>>},
           {:Validity, {:utcTime, '160428162930Z'}, {:utcTime, '170528162930Z'}},
           :asn1_NOVALUE,
           :asn1_NOVALUE,
           :asn1_NOVALUE,
           :asn1_NOVALUE,
           :asn1_NOVALUE}}
```

In order to find the `:Validity` tuple, I need to do

```
tuple |> elem(1) |> elem(4)
```

I can do a pattern matching, but there's too much `:asn1_NOVALUE` in the 
end I just want to ignore them.

Is there other way in Erlang/Elixir to get the nested tuple value? Something like

```
get_in(tuple, [:Certificate, :Validity])
```

Comment: It looks like an Erlang record so you probably should use elixir's `Record` module which will provide some macros for an easy access :)

Comment: The tuple result was from http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html#pem_entry_decode-2, looked into `Record.extract/2`, though after reading the documentation still not sure how to use that..

Comment: Which version of Erlang are you using? I was going to write an answer using Record macros but it looks like Erlang 19 has an additional field before AlgorithmIdentifier in TBSCertificate record.

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/public_key/public_key_records.html) the definition of the record `'TBSCertificate'`:

```
'TBSCertificate'{
      version,              % v1 | v2 | v3 
      serialNumber,         % integer() 
      signature,            % #'AlgorithmIdentifier'{} 
      issuer,               % {rdnSequence, [#AttributeTypeAndValue'{}]} 
      validity,             % #'Validity'{}
      subject,              % {rdnSequence, [#AttributeTypeAndValue'{}]} 
      subjectPublicKeyInfo, % #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{}
      issuerUniqueID,       % binary() | asn1_novalue
      subjectUniqueID,      % binary() | asn1_novalue
      extensions            % [#'Extension'{}] 
     }.
```

It is erlang notation, but I guess it will be equivalent with elixir. In erlang you can retrieve the information `'Validity'` using the record syntax:

```
{_,TBScert} = Tuple,
Validity = Tuple#'TBSCertificate'.'Validity' % which is also a record
```

I am not familiar with elixir's syntax, I think it is something like

```
{_,tbs_cert} = tuple,
validity = :TBSCertificate(tbs_cert, :Validity),
```

But I cant't test it. The definition of the `'Validity'` record is:

```
'Validity'{ 
      notBefore, % time()
      notAfter   % time()
     }.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
with {:Certificate, cert} <- tuple,
     [_, _, _, _, {:Validity, v1, v2} | _] <- Tuple.to_list(cert),
do: {v1, v2}
%⇒ {{:utcTime, '160428162930Z'}, {:utcTime, '170528162930Z'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract record information from `public_key.hrl`

```elixir
require Record
Record.defrecord :certificate Record.extract(:Certificate, from_lib: "public_key/include/public_key.hrl")
Record.defrecord :TBSCertificate Record.extract(:TBSCertificate, from_lib: "public_key/include/public_key.hrl")
Record.defrecord :validity Record.extract(:Validity, from_lib: "public_key/include/public_key.hrl")
```

Then you can write pattern match

```elixir
certificate(tbsCertificate: TBSCert) = Tuple,
TBSCertificate(Validity: valid) = TBSCert,
validity(notBefore: from, notAfter: to) = valid,
```

I don't know Elixir enough to know if this would work as well

```elixir
certificate(tbsCertificate: TBSCertificate(Validity: validity(notBefore: from, notAfter: to))) = Tuple,
```